# Visual Studio Express 2017 Output not displaying for stroke text function

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I've been trying to run this program in visual studio express 2017. Using opengl.
I found the rendering code and stroke code in a pdf and was trying it out but first it showed many errors, once taken care of I compiled the program. Although the run was without any errors the output screen remains blank.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>

void myInit(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLineWidth(6.0);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 700, 0.0, 700);
}

void drawStrokeText(const char *string, int x, int y, int z)
{
    const char *c;
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y + 8, z);
    glScalef(0.09f, -0.08f, z);
    for (c = string; *c != '\0'; c++)
    {
        glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *c);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3ub(255, 50, 255);
    drawStrokeText("Hello", 300, 400, 0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    render();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(700, 700);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("My First Program");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix mode is switched to `GL_PROJECTION` in `myInit` but never switched back. Therefore the `glLoadIdentity()` instruction in `render` will override the projection matrix. You have to switch the matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW` before `glLoadIdentity()`:

```cpp
void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // <--
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3ub(255, 50, 255);
    drawStrokeText("Hello", 300, 400, 0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```